# Autocomplete Textview - select only particular text rather than entire

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Suppose, A autocompletetextview will provide multiple text data out of which, i want to display particular text only in autocompletetextview by discarding other data.

Example:

Textview options are:

goog - Google Inc
yhoo - Yahoo
msft - Microsoft Corporation

if user select the first one, the autocompletetextview should contain only goog.

I've no idea..how do i begin. Please can u explain me with one example.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could set this up with a structure as key/value. 
goog will be the key, and goog - Google Inc yhoo - Yahoo msft - Microsoft Corporation  the value.

In either a database, or a suitable Collection you'd be simply able to find the other, no matter if you provide the key or the value.